# Can the tableau proof be used on $X$ instead of $\neg X$?

Tags: logic

I know you can show that $X$ is a tautology when all branches of $\neg X$ close. But is it equivalent to prove that no branch of $X$ itself closes?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the tableau for $X$ does not close, this shows that $X$ is *satisfiable*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider $X = P$, i.e. some atomic proposition. Then the tableau has no closed branches, but $X$ is not a tautology.

And by the way, it is also not true that if $X$ is a tautology, there will be no closed bracnhes.

Consider $X=(P \land \neg P) \lor (Q \lor \neg Q)$

$X$ is a tautology, but in the tableau for $X$, you get a branch with $P \land \neg P$ in one of the branches ... which will quickly close.

In sum, it is definitely not true that a statement is a tautology if and only if its tableau has no closed branches: you can have non-tautologies without an closed branches, and  you can have a tautology that does have closed branches.